# How does placement new work?

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, placement-new

I wrote the following thinking that it should segfault at runtime.
However it does not, it runs fine, and I don't understand why.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <new>

struct MyStruct
{
    double *a;

    MyStruct()
        : a(NULL) 
        { printf("Default constructor\n"); }
    MyStruct( double *b )
        : a(b) 
        {}
    MyStruct( const MyStruct& other )
    {
        printf("Copy-constructor\n");
        if ( a != NULL && *a != 3.14 )
            a = other.a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    double num = 3.14;
    MyStruct obj( &num );

    void *ptr = ::operator new( sizeof(MyStruct) );
    new (ptr) MyStruct(obj);

    delete (MyStruct*) ptr; // Calls ~MyStruct
}
```

The output is:

```
Copy-constructor
```

When I write `void *ptr = ::operator new( sizeof(MyStruct) );` I know this only allocates memory, and should not call the default constructor. And it doesn't seem to: fine.

When I write `new (ptr) MyStruct(obj);`, I would expect it to segfault, if it worked like I thought. I think this is equivalent to `( (MyStruct*) ptr )->MyStruct(obj)`.
If so, the line `if ( a != NULL && *a != 3.14 )` should reach `*a != 3.14` and segfault, because `a` has not been initialized.

My problem is that `a` doesn't seem to have been initialized (because there was no output "Default constructor"), but the previous still doesn't segfault. What am I missing?

---

Here is the assembly code generated (I don't know how to read it):

```
    .file   "placement_new.cpp"
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align  8
.LCPI0_0:
    .quad   4614253070214989087     # double 3.1400000000000001
    .text
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    push    rbp
.Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset rbp, -16
    mov rbp, rsp
.Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register rbp
    sub rsp, 48
    lea rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 24]
    lea rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 16]
    movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [.LCPI0_0]
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
    movsd   qword ptr [rbp - 16], xmm0
    call    _ZN8MyStructC2EPd
    movabs  rdi, 8
    call    _Znwm
    mov qword ptr [rbp - 32], rax
    mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 32]
    cmp rax, 0
    mov qword ptr [rbp - 40], rax # 8-byte Spill
    je  .LBB0_2
# BB#1:
    lea rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 24]
    mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 40] # 8-byte Reload
    mov rdi, rax
    call    _ZN8MyStructC2ERKS_
.LBB0_2:
    mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 32]
    cmp rax, 0
    mov qword ptr [rbp - 48], rax # 8-byte Spill
    je  .LBB0_4
# BB#3:
    mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 48] # 8-byte Reload
    mov rdi, rax
    call    _ZdlPv
.LBB0_4:
    mov eax, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
    add rsp, 48
    pop rbp
    ret
.Ltmp5:
    .size   main, .Ltmp5-main
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    .text._ZN8MyStructC2EPd,"axG",@progbits,_ZN8MyStructC2EPd,comdat
    .weak   _ZN8MyStructC2EPd
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8MyStructC2EPd,@function
_ZN8MyStructC2EPd:                      # @_ZN8MyStructC2EPd
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    push    rbp
.Ltmp8:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp9:
    .cfi_offset rbp, -16
    mov rbp, rsp
.Ltmp10:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register rbp
    mov qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
    mov qword ptr [rbp - 16], rsi
    mov rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
    mov rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 16]
    mov qword ptr [rsi], rdi
    pop rbp
    ret
.Ltmp11:
    .size   _ZN8MyStructC2EPd, .Ltmp11-_ZN8MyStructC2EPd
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align  8
.LCPI2_0:
    .quad   4614253070214989087     # double 3.1400000000000001
    .section    .text._ZN8MyStructC2ERKS_,"axG",@progbits,_ZN8MyStructC2ERKS_,comdat
    .weak   _ZN8MyStructC2ERKS_
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8MyStructC2ERKS_,@function
_ZN8MyStructC2ERKS_:                    # @_ZN8MyStructC2ERKS_
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    push    rbp
.Ltmp14:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp15:
    .cfi_offset rbp, -16
    mov rbp, rsp
.Ltmp16:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register rbp
    sub rsp, 32
    lea rax, qword ptr [.L.str]
    mov qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
    mov qword ptr [rbp - 16], rsi
    mov rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
    mov rdi, rax
    mov al, 0
    mov qword ptr [rbp - 24], rsi # 8-byte Spill
    call    printf
    mov rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 24] # 8-byte Reload
    cmp qword ptr [rsi], 0
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 28], eax # 4-byte Spill
    je  .LBB2_3
# BB#1:
    movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [.LCPI2_0]
    mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 24] # 8-byte Reload
    mov rcx, qword ptr [rax]
    movsd   xmm1, qword ptr [rcx]
    ucomisd xmm1, xmm0
    jne .LBB2_2
    jp  .LBB2_2
    jmp .LBB2_3
.LBB2_2:
    mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 16]
    mov rax, qword ptr [rax]
    mov rcx, qword ptr [rbp - 24] # 8-byte Reload
    mov qword ptr [rcx], rax
.LBB2_3:
    add rsp, 32
    pop rbp
    ret
.Ltmp17:
    .size   _ZN8MyStructC2ERKS_, .Ltmp17-_ZN8MyStructC2ERKS_
    .cfi_endproc

    .type   .L.str,@object          # @.str
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.L.str:
    .asciz  "Copy-constructor\n"
    .size   .L.str, 18


    .ident  "Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Comment: Compile a release version and try again.

Comment: `What am I missing?`  You're missing the simple fact that when you do nutty things in C++, it doesn't mean that the program will crash.

Comment: Note that this code has undefined behavior: you _cannot_ `delete` and object created with placement `new`. You need to destruct it and release the memory separately: `mptr->~MyStruct(); operator delete(ptr);` (where `mptr` is the `MyStruct*` returned from the placement `new`).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That doesn't answer my question though :)

Comment: Your copy constructor `MyStruct::MyStruct` is flawed: it uses `MyStruct::a` without having initialised it. If not using optimisation flags, the compiler may auto-initialise it to null (and your code magically works), but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: There is only one `new` expression. The first lexical appearance of the word `new` is just an ordinary function call.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yes, but in this case, there is nothing to do for destruction. It doesn't change the problem anyway.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Yes it does. See this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271299/undefined-behavior-in-principle/271304#271304). There can be practical answers to questions about undefined behavior, but asking "why doesn't my program crash?" is the wrong approach.

Comment: @remyabel Got it, thanks. Well then could anyone explain in details how placement new proceeds then? Is it indeed equivalent to `( (MyStruct*) ptr )->MyStruct(obj)` in my case?

Comment: It's trivial to turn this into correct code, though: just say: `MyStruct * p = new (ptr) MyStruct(obj); p->~MyStruct(); ::operator delete(ptr);` (You may even want to say `::new (ptr) MyStruct(obj)` to remove the possibility of using an overloaded placement-new operator.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: not that it doesn't matter whether the destructor has anything to do or not: undefined behavior just means you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn - If you want to know what is happening, look at the generated assembly code. Nothing stops a compiler from wiping out those lines of code you think are being executed.

Comment: I've removed my first comment. I'm not actually sure if the present code is UB, since `delete` only requires an operand that is the result of *some* *new-expression* (though the array-vs-non-arrayness has to match), not necessarily one syntactically identical. An effect of a `delete` expression is that some deallocation function is called, but there seems to be considerable freedom in which deallocation function may be found, and I can't find anything that's explicitly UB. And there's this business with extendable and mergeable allocations, too.

Comment: (With your last edit you definitely introduced UB since you now have a double deletion. You need to only deallocate the storage in the last step, not call the destructor again.)

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: Correct, a `delete` expression invokes destructors.

Comment: @Walter I just saw your comment. Using `a` without initialization is intended to cause a segfault. I wanted to know how placement new worked, and in particular whether the default-constructor was called before the copy constructor (eg to 'sanitize' the memory before using it) but apparently not. I think you are right but I compiled it with `-O3` and `a` is still being initialized to `NULL` (tested with an if statement before the print in the copy constructor). Any chance you can help me with assembly code? I want to know what's compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a variable which has not been initialized is undefined behavior.  It is not unreasonable then that your compiler sets the pointer's value to NULL before assignment, which would cause a [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) on the `if` statement in your copy constructor and thus `*a` would never be executed.

Comment: This seems to be what happens at runtime. However I would like to check whether this behaviour has been compiled, or if it is just by chance, any chance you can help me with the assembly code?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn You won't see that in the assembly code. It might be hidden in the C runtime (specifically, the implementation of malloc) or even deeper: for example, on Windows, if the allocated memory happens to be on a new memory page, the physical RAM behind it will be zeroed out by a completely different process.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Thanks, it would be nice to know whether this is systematic or not though.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn If you mean whether you can rely on this behavior, the answer is no. Using `a` before it is initialized is undefined behavior, plain and simple. In fact, since the only situation where `a` would have a defined value here would be for an object with static lifetime (globals, function-statics, class-statics) and the defined value in this case would be `NULL`, a compiler could just remove your entire `if` block: in the only case that has defined behavior, the first condition is false.

Answer (score 1):

The call to placement `new` is OK: what should be wrong with it: it gets enough memory to place an object into it. It should, of course, use the copy constructor given that you call it with `obj` as parameter. Whether this output appears are not, though, is up in the air: `printf()` buffers its memory and since you cause undefined behavior after this construction by calling `delete (MyStruct*)ptr;`, i.e., on a pointer not obtained by non-placement `new`, the code may easily crash before the library flushes the buffer (it prints that the copy constructor was used on my system).

To properly destroy your object you need to use something like this:

```
MyStruct* mptr = new(ptr) MyStruct(obj);
mptr->~MyStrucT();
operator delete(ptr);
```

Actually, there is also undefined behavior with respect to the member of `a` during copy construction: the members are not implicitly copied. That is, you are accessing uninitialized memory in the copy constructor which can also do whatever it wants.

Comment: This shouldn't change anything though (just checked, it doesn't), there's nothing to do for destruction. Cf. my edit, I added the destruction before the `delete` statement.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: yes, of course, `a` is not initialized by the copy constructor: why do you think it would be called? The copy constructor is responsible for initializing its members but it doesn't. Did you mean to write `MyStruct(MyStruct const& other): MyStruct() { ... }`?

Comment: Nope, this is why I would expect the program to crash; I'm not sure I understand fully the extent of "undefined behaviour". It's not a magic word that says that my code doesn't make sense; the code compiles and runs, and most likely executes what is written. When I write `*a != 3.14`, it should try to dereference a pointer that hasn't been initialized; this should segfault.

Comment: Undefined behavior means, whatever happens can happen. It may crash, it may launch a nuclear missile stationed close to you (or one targeted at the area you are currently located at), it may cause nasal daemons to be emitted, or nothing happening at all. If you want it to to crash, you could try `memset(ptr, 0x3f, sizeof(MyStruct))` to arrange for the pointer to be non-null and point to [probably] unmapped memory. However, there is no guarantee for a crash...

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Required reading: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: I can't actually find a reference that you have to match `new` and `delete` expressions syntactically; there's even a note: "this means that the syntax of the *delete-expression* must match the type of the object allocated by `new`, not the syntax of the *new-expression*." There seems to be a lot of freedom regarding which deallocation function is found.

Comment: In fact, [expr.delete]/(7.1) says, "The value returned from the allocation call of the *new-expression* shall be passed as the first argument to the deallocation function." Since the value returned from the (placement) new expression is just `ptr`, this very value gets passed to the deallocation function. If the `delete` expression were spelled `::delete`, then this would find the matching deallocation function.

Comment: I was wondering, considering I'm doing "read-only" stuff with my non-initialized pointer, would this technically even segfault?

Comment: @KerrekSB: The note refers to this use `typedef int array[10]; delete[] new array;` (note: no `[]` in the `new` expression but the `[]` is required in the `delete` expression. I'll find the other quote (it is somewhere...).

Comment: @KerrekSB: the case is clear if the allocation function is something other then `operator new(std::size_t)` or `operator new(std::size_t, std::nothrow_t)`. In case one of these versions is used for the argument of the placement `new` it may be OK to `delete` the resulting pointer: I can't find a statement making it undefined behavior.